# Ajax not calling back when request complete

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm uploading the image via AJAX but success is not calling on complete.

I have these 2 objects exits inside a form.

```
<img class="b_logo" id="b_logo_img" src="images/no_image.gif"> 
<input class="file_up" id="file_logo" type="file">
```

The data contain the URL for the image.

```
$(function() {

    $("#file_logo:file").change(function (){
       var fileName = $(this).val();
       savepic();
    });

});

function savepic()
{
var file_data = $("#file_logo").prop("files")[0]; // Getting the properties of file from file field
var form_data = new FormData(); // Creating object of FormData class
form_data.append("file", file_data) // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
form_data.append("user_id", 123) // Adding extra parameters to form_data
$.ajax({
url: "support_file/upload_image.php",
dataType: 'script',
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
data: form_data, // Setting the data attribute of ajax with file_data
type: 'post',
success: function (data) {
$("#b_logo_img").attr("src",data);
}
});
}
```

Response
[image]

Comment: What are you seeing in the http response (examine it from your dev tools)?

Comment: 200 POST, and getting the data /uploads/1409167352.jpg

Comment: Check dataType : 'script', are you returning script data or something else ?

Comment: What is in the response? Is there any data being returned? Are you certain the success callback isn't firing, or are you just not seeing what you expect?

Comment: I added the picture of response please see.

Comment: whats in support_file/upload_image.php?

Comment: script to upload file

Comment: If you console.log the data in your success response, you don't see anything? Based on what you've described and the screenshot of your response, it looks like it should be working.

Comment: But the success is not triggering on complete success: function (data) {
$("#b_logo_img").attr("src",data);
}

Comment: Try removing the dataType field and do a console.log(data) in your success function just to see if it returns.

Comment: Thanks by removing data type it works. @eluong you are the star.

Comment: Glad to help :). I just put it in an answer so readers can see it rather wading through the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `dataType: 'script'` works.

Answer (score 1):

**This should work fine**

1) Try using a form to get the image file name and send it to the php instead of getting it the way you are getting.

2) Always empty the style attribute of the img tag when you are dynamically changing its src

```
$("#file_logo").change(function()  
    { var formData = new FormData($("#form_id")[0]);



        $.ajax({
            url: "name_of_your_php_page.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (info) {
                $("#b_logo_img").attr('src',info).fadeIn();
                $("#b_logo_img").attr('style',' '); 
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
return false;
```

`});`